# AWS Free Usage Tier Windows query

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, cloud-hosting

very new to EC2 and looking to start playing with it through the "AWS Free Usage Tier" as outlined here http://aws.amazon.com/free/
It does not list that you can select a Windows OS to play with. 
Is it possible to select a windows OS and is it free if you keep within limits?
Thanks Noel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your link:

> AWS Free Usage Tier (Per Month): 750
>   hours of Amazon EC2 **Linux Micro**
>   Instance usage

Answer (score 0):

[Since 2012](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/01/15/AWS-Free-Tier-Now-Includes-Windows/), Amazon also offers Windows in their free tier:

> 750 hours of Amazon EC2 Microsoft Windows Server‡ Micro Instance usage (613 MB of memory and 32-bit and 64-bit platform support) – enough hours to run continuously each month*